Are there linguistic maps/infographs of the typology of the manifestation of stress
On WALS, Chapters about stress:
14 Fixed Stress Locations
15 Weight-Sensitive Stress
16 Weight Factors in Weight-Sensitive Stress Systems
17 Rhythm Types

It is much much more difficult to define stress solely phonetically than tone.
According to Hyman, word stress is obligatory, culminative, privative and metrical. The stressed syllable is more prominent in terms of loudness/ vowel length/ vowel quality/ tone.
English is a canonical stress language and there are many marginal cases eg. some languages have word stress that is not obligatory but culminative.
Moreover, for some languages, the stress system does not align with the tone system (eg. Latvian).
Here, I would like to have a typology map about the manifestation of stress in detail such as:
A) Stress is (mainly) manifested by pitch only (so called pitch-accent)
B) Stress is manifested by significantly strengthened segments (mostly stress-timed languages eg. English Russian) along with other features
C) Stress is manifested by everything listed above except significantly strengthened segments (eg. Spanish??)
D) Other special cases eg. by vowel length and loudness but not tone nor strengthened segments

In what language?? One is the stress a word takes (tonic accent) takes and the other is the stress over the utterance, which is any word, say, in English, depending on the meaning you are trying to convey. So...

linguistic maps (akin to those on WALS) of typology of word stress

'On WALS, Chapters about stress:…' and its following numbered titles seem to refer to a specific publication, which suggests there is a Link missing here.
Am I mistaken, or can you Posts that Link?
